# How to write a function that accepts multiple parameters separated by the pipe symbol?

Tags: java, android

For instance, in Android, adding flags to an intent using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SOME_ACTION);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

How would that method look?

Comment: Try using ```int```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe symbol is the *bitwise inclusive OR* operator. The operator compares the values (in binary format) of each operand and yields a value whose bit pattern shows which bits in either of the operands has the value 1. If both of the bits are 0, the result of that bit is 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

The code in your case may look like this:

```java
public class Intent {
  
  // define flag constants
  public static final int FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK = 1; 
  public static final int FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION = 2;
  
  private int flags;

  public void setFlags(int flags) {
    this.flags = flags;
  }
  
}
```

You can call the method like this afterwards:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

You can learn more about bitwise operators in [the official Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) or look at these guides:

- [Java Bitwise Operators](https://www.baeldung.com/java-bitwise-operators)
- [Bitwise Operators in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-java/)

Comment: I think I understand - it just isn't clicking yet.  I can and do write code leveraging it without hesitation but I want it to intuitively make sense.  I'll accept this answer in a little while and thanks for writing it.